# Is this the correct way to play the "Spoon" card?

Tags: sushi-go, sushi-go-party

Whenever we play the game with the "Spoon," we always follow these steps:

> First, all players choose a card from their own hands. Then, *before*
>   the cards are revealed, call out "spoon!" and announce the name of any
>   card you would like. Starting from the player to your left, he checks
>   to see if he has this card in his current hand *(which of course excludes the card he was about to reveal)*. If not, the second player checks her current
>   hand, and so on until a player announces they have the card. Take this
>   card, and give the **SPOON** to the player whose card you took, and all
>   players then reveal their cards simultaneously.

I always thought this was the proper way to play the "Spoon" card, because it prevents you from knowing if a player will or will not play a certain card, such as the "Miso Soup," unless of course if the card that you were asking was already chosen by the player and was about to reveal prior to playing the "Spoon" card.

Answer (score 2):

Spoon and chopsticks are bonus action cards. From the rule book’s description:

> [To use a bonus action card, simply call out the name of the card **as all players are revealing the cards during a turn**. After all players have played their chosen cards as normal, the called out action then takes effect.](http://www.gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/SushiGoPartyTM-RULES.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain what your asking, it seems you just want confirmation your interpretation is correct which I don't think it is.

Firstly the Spoon card is from Sushi Go Party, not Sushi Go.  Using the rules [here](http://www.gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/SushiGoPartyTM-RULES.pdf) as a reference it seems you've got the order a little wrong.

On page 7 it states :-

> Chopsticks and spoon cards allow you to
>   perform a bonus action on any turn after the
>   turn in which the card is originally played.
>   To use a bonus action card, simply call out the
>   name of the card as all players are revealing
>   the cards during a turn. After all players have
>   played their chosen cards as normal, the called
>   out action then takes effect.

This order is the reiterated on page 13.

> When you want to use it, call out “spoon!” as all players are
>   revealing their played cards. All players play their chosen cards
>   as normal. Then announce the name of any card you would like.

So it's clear than a player can ask for what card they want AFTER all cards have been played and not before as you say in your example.

Finally on page of 11 for the "Miso soup" example you gave it states :-

> • If a player plays a miso soup by using chopsticks, spoon, menu, or
>   special order it counts as being played on that same turn.

So there is no reason why a spoon using player couldn't ask for Miso Soup to score point or deny points to another player.

Comment: This is how my friends and I play Chopsticks & Spoon: (1) We first place our first card face-down on the table, (2) Call out the action, (3) Do the action of the card, (4) Return the card to your/opponent's hand, and (5) Finally reveal the cards. I tend to oppose the rules because it gave me major confusion. And I also thought about the "Miso Soup" thing. If we're gonna follow the rules, what if you wanna play or get a "Miso Soup" but one of the players already revealed a "Miso Soup," then you can't choose it at all because it'll just be discarded (unless you wanna mess with your friends).

Comment: I think your questions was about if your reading of rules was.  If you like the rules or not is probably more an opinion based thing which wouldn't have a clear answer.